# Breaking out of a foreach within a nested if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo, foreach

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to break a section out of a an else-statement that is nested within a `foreach` loop.

The section I want to break out of the foreach loop is :

```
echo '
  <div class="moreEventsContainer">
  <div id="moreEventsWrap" class="total-center">
  <span class="moreEventsLink">SEE ALL EVENTS</span>
  <div class="rightArrow"></div>
  </div>
  </div>'
;
```

The thing is that it is part of the else statement, but leaving it in the loop just makes it duplicate itself over and over when I just want it to appear once.

Does anyone see how I can do this?

I tried doing the alternative `endforeach` nested before the end of the else statement, but it just broke the code.

Any ideas?

```
foreach ($event_rows as $event_row) {
        $event_name = $event_row['event_name'];
        $display_date = $event_row['display_date'];
        $event_description = $event_row['small_desc'];
        $end_date = new DateTime($event_row['end_date']);
        $date = new DateTime('now');
        if ($date >= $end_date) {
            //$noEvents = 'No events are scheduled yet.';
            $noEvents = '
            <div id="noEvents">
            </div>
            ';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="eventBlock">';
            echo '<div class="total-center eventBlockWrap">';
            echo '<span class="displayDate">'. $display_date .'</span>';
            echo '<span class="eventName">'. $event_name .'</span>';
            echo '<p class="dGsmall margNone">'. $event_description .'</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="moreEventsContainer">
                    <div id="moreEventsWrap" class="total-center">
                        <span class="moreEventsLink">SEE ALL EVENTS</span>
                        <div class="rightArrow"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>'
            ;
        }
    }
    if ($noEvents != NULL) {
        echo $noEvents;
    } else {

    }
```

Update:

```
foreach ($event_rows as $event_row) {
        $event_name = $event_row['event_name'];
        $display_date = $event_row['display_date'];
        $event_description = $event_row['small_desc'];
        $end_date = new DateTime($event_row['end_date']);
        $date = new DateTime('now');
        if ($date >= $end_date) {
            //$noEvents = 'No events are scheduled yet.';
            $noEvents = '
            <div id="noEvents">
            </div>
            ';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="eventBlock">';
            echo '<div class="total-center eventBlockWrap">';
            echo '<span class="displayDate">'. $display_date .'</span>';
            echo '<span class="eventName">'. $event_name .'</span>';
            echo '<p class="dGsmall margNone">'. $event_description .'</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            break;
            echo '<div class="moreEventsContainer">
                    <div id="moreEventsWrap" class="total-center">
                        <span class="moreEventsLink">SEE ALL EVENTS</span>
                        <div class="rightArrow"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>'
            ;
        }
 }
```

Comment: I want to break out of the foreach loop - try `break`

Comment: `I just want it to appear once.` -> so you want  else data need to be printed at least 1 time no matter what case will be there?(even in the case that  every-time if condition will true)

Comment: I updated my question with new code. I tried the break method and it only outputs one row from my database. I have several records in there that I want to output, but then the part after the break I want to appear only once.

Comment: @Paul  read my comment once and answer please

Comment: @AlivetoDie I want the `echo '<div class="moreEventsContainer">` in the else to appear only once. So, if I have 100 records in my database, I want all 100 records to loop through and output, then the `moreEventsContainer` to display once after that....only if the condition is else.

Comment: if all time condition will true then else will not come so if 100 record will there and all 100 is printing then why you expecting else to be print-out once at least?

Comment: @AllivetoDie Sorry, not sure what you mean. My if/else isn't the issue. It is working fine. Could you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

According to your update,
I suppose you want this code

```
echo '<div class="moreEventsContainer">
        <div id="moreEventsWrap" class="total-center">
          <span class="moreEventsLink">SEE ALL EVENTS</span>
              <div class="rightArrow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>';
```

to execute once, after all of your records are shown.

So, I suggest using this instead of the `break` statement

```
if($i==sizeof($event_rows)){
    echo '<div class="moreEventsContainer">
    <div id="moreEventsWrap" class="total-center">
      <span class="moreEventsLink">SEE ALL EVENTS</span>
          <div class="rightArrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>';
}
```

Where `$i` is initialized to `1` and incremented each time the loop executes.

Comment: Could you go further into this? Why would having $i incrementally increase solve this?

Comment: So, sizeof() function gives us the length of the array. Which means if you have 100 records sitting inside your variable, sizeof() will return 100.
using a counter variable $i would help us track if its the last record or not. So, by incrementing $i till its the size of an array, we know that we've reached the last record and we can print the div "moreEventsContainer".

Comment: @Paul do you have any other queries about sizeof() or incrementation